# How can I pass data from JSP page to a Java Servlet without using form?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have been trying to pass the data from a JSP page to a Java Servlet without using form. The JSP form returns to itself (action="") and I validate the form element. Then I want to pass the inputs of the user to Java Servlet. Couldn't find a good solution. Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you are looking for, if you want to pass parameters to Servlet without using form you can simple try this, but you need to add your parameters on the link
this is an example.

```
 <a href="ServletName?theNameOfParameterToSend=TheValueOfTheParameter&anotherNameOfParameterToSend=TheAotherValueOfTheParameter>
```

this is real example

```
<a href="MyApp?currancy=usd&country=usa>Send</a>
```

By using this way you can't send data by String query in post, it will be always visible in the link.

Wish I was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solved my problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try Ajax.

I use Ajax Asynchronous Verify that the account exists.

If the account does not exist, you will be prompted below.

It can pass data without refreshing the page.

Here is my related code.

```java
public User getUserByName(String name) {
        User user = null;
        try {
            conn = DBUtils.getConnection();
            String sql = "select id,name,pwd from user_info where `name`=?";
            statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, name);
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                user = new User();
                user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DBUtils.close(conn, statement, resultSet);
        }
        return user;
    }
public class CheckNameServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        UserDao userDao = new UserDaoImpl();
        User user = userDao.getUserByName(name);
        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        if (user == null) {
            pw.print(1);
        } else {
            pw.print(0);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkName() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "check",
            data: {"name": name},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "0") {
                    $("#msg").html("");
                } else {
                    $("#msg").html("The account does not exist, please re-enter!")
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

then put  `msg` in your HTML.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I manually constructed a GET URL to solve my problem.